# Compiling Libvirt-snmp on VMware ESXi

Tags: vmware, snmp, libvirt, esxi

How can I compile and run Libvirt-snmp on VMware Vsphere ESXi? Can somebody guide with step by step procedure.

I tried to followed steps mentioned on [Libvirt Website](https://libvirt.org/compiling.html)
but I guess they are for Linux distribution. Because I could not execute `./configure` command.

After searching on Google I found a [similar question](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/514078) which tells that I need to create a VIB and than install that VIB. Now I have no idea about creating VIB. Can somebody please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody guide with step by step procedure.
>   As a workaround
>   1. Have a Linux VM and create a nfs share
>   2. Install and configure the required tool. [in your case, the libvirt] in the linux VM in the nfs share. Note the export path and variables
>   3. Mount the nfs share as NAS volume in ESXi 
>   4. Give a soft link to the mounted nas volume to /usr/bin in ESXi
>   5. Create corresponding directory tree under /usr/local/lib as required by the tool and link them too to the nfs share.

And you are good to run the tool.

> Now I have no idea about creating VIB
>   Simply put, VIB is VMware Infrastructure Bundle which is the allowed method to push pgms inside ESXi. You can use ar command to create a vib from a rpm and use vib author too to push the module inside ESXi.
>   Hope it helps